# Convert single element in array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert all elements of a given key in a list of objects. The specific change is to convert an generic `object` to a [`Long`](https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js) object with the same values.

Input:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]
```

Where each object looks like:

```
{
    key1: value1, // value1 is an object
    key2: value2
}
```

So the goal here is to get a very similar array, but where `key1` is transformed from just `object` to a `long` object, in my example incremented by one.

Output:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

Where each object is:

```
{
    key1: value1, // value1 is now a Long object
    key2: value2
}
```

I tried with mapping over the array and then spreading over the objects entries, but did not succeed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The code you tried really should be part of the question.

Comment: should be a _very_ simple map. What did you try?

Comment: please add some real example with the wanted result, beside the code, you tried.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the question to be more specific. I also added an answer below with the final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers guys.

I ended up with the following:

Given the input

```
[
    {
        key1: value1, // value1 is an object
        key2: value2
    },

    {
        key1: value1, // value1 is also an object
        key2: value2
    }
]
```

**Solution:**
I ended up with,

```
  const testvar = [obj1, obj2, obj3].map((obj) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      key1: new Long.fromValue(obj.key1)
    }
  });

  console.log(testvar);
```

Which gives the output

```
[
    {
        key1: value1, // value1 is now a Long object
        key2: value2
    },

    {
        key1: value1, // value1 is also now a Long object
        key2: value2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to map here, unless you want to create one more new array. Simple loop would be enough, just update `key1` or each object:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3].forEach(obj => {
  obj.key1 = obj.key1 + 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the array holds object - any modification to object reflect the actual input being passed. You need to make a copy of your object and perform the logic.

Your logic,

```
var input = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
var output = input.map(function(obj){
    obj.key1 = obj.key1 + 1;
    return obj;
});

console.log(input[0]===output[0]); //true
```

**Solution:**

```
var output = input.map(function(obj){
    var _objCopy = Object.assign({}, obj);
    _objCopy.key1 = _objCopy.key1 + 1;
    return _objCopy;
});

console.log(input[0]===output[0]); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

how about dynamically first key of any object es6 way

```
 const myObject0 = {
           'foo1': { name: 'myNam1' },
           'foo2': { name: 'myNam2' }
        };

        const myObject1 = {
           'yo': { name: 'myNam1' },
           'boh': { name: 'myNam2' }
        };


        [myObject0, myObject1].forEach(obj => {
            let getFirstKey = Object.keys(obj)[0];
            getFirstKey = getFirstKey + 1;
            console.log(getFirstKey);

        });
```